# Example of Double Counting

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to work on counting skills and came up with the following problem, however I feel that I am running into an issue of double counting or counting faulty cases.

Say there are 9 distinct birds flying in small groups.
Any 4 may be leaders and any 5 may be followers, but each leader must have at least ONE follower.  What number of combinations of leader/followers exist?

Attempt at solution:using n choose k: $\displaystyle\binom nk$

$\displaystyle\binom94  \left[\binom52  \binom31  \binom21  \binom11+ \binom51  \binom42  \binom21  \binom11 +\binom51  \binom41  \binom32  \binom11 + \binom51 \binom41  \binom31  \binom22\right]$

I realize I may be counting cases where a leader(s) is without a follower... though I am not sure how to account for this.  Is there a way to account for invalid cases with basic combination methods? (I am assuming there is a mistake here.)

Comment: Does every bird have to be a leader or a follower? I mean, can there be one leader, one follower and seven normal birds, say?

Comment: All birds must be either leader/follower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach I see is $9c4$ ways to pick the leaders, $4$ to pick which leader gets two followers, $5c2$ to get the two followers, $3!$ to arrange the other three followers among the leaders, so 
$$9c4 \cdot 4 \cdot 5c2 \cdot 3!=126 \cdot 4 \cdot 10 \cdot 6=30240$$

Comment: Thank you. My method seemed to return the same value, and I was concerned my method counted cases where leaders had no followers.  Your explanation is more intuitive and makes perfect sense.